# Pause and Resume video recording for a room in twilio?

Tags: javascript, rest, video, twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible to Pause and Resume video recording for a room in twilio ? Use case may include pause and resume recording manually through UI or recording only starts when particular participant joins, etc.
Didn't find much in twilio docs regarding it.

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no pause or resume functionality for Twilio Programmable Video.